# Series representation of polynomial root

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, roots, quintics

Consider the quintic:
$$(1+q)x^5-(2+3q)x^4+(1+3q)x^3-x^2+2x-1=0$$
for $q=0$, this equation has a triple root:
$$(1-x)^3(x^2+x+1)=0 \implies x=1.$$
Kopal (1959) then states that, for small $q$, a series representation of this root is:
$$x = 1-w+\frac{1}{3}w^2+\frac{1}{9}w^3+ ...,$$
with
$$w^3 = \frac{q}{3(1+q)}.$$
How does one go about finding this expansion? A standard Taylor expansion does not work, as the derivative $x'(q)$ is infinite at $q=0$. Also, we seem to be expanding in the cube root of the small number. How does $w$ given above surface from the polynomial? Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Since we know $w^3 = f(x)$, the Lagrange inversion theorem gives
$$a_k = \frac 1 {k!} \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac {d^{k - 1}} {dx^{k - 1}} \left(
 \frac {x - 1} {f^{1/3}(x)} \right)^{\! k} =
\frac {(-1)^k} {k!} \left. \frac {d^{k - 1}} {dx^{k - 1}} \left(
  \frac {3 - 6 x + 3 x^2 + 6 x^3 - 3 x^4} {1 + x + x^2} \right)^{\! k/3}
 \right|_{x = 1}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We consider the smooth functions $q:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f,F:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
q(w) &= \frac {3w^3}{1-3w^3}\ ,
\\[3mm]
f(q,x) &= (1+q)x^5-(2+3q)x^4+(1+3q)x^3-x^2+2x-1\\
&=(x-1)^3(x^2+x+1) +qx^3(x^2-3x+3)\\
&=(x-1)^3(x^2+x+1) +qx^2(x-1)^3 +qx^3
\\[3mm]
F(w,x)
&=f(q(w),x)\\
&=(x-1)^3(x^2+x+1) + \frac{3w^3}{1-3w^3}\;x^3(x^2-3x+3)
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and note that $F(0,1)=f(0,1)=0$.

We apply the Implicit Function Theorem (IFT) for $f$, so that we obtain $x$ as a function of $q$ first. For this we note that the corresponding derivative $f'_q=x^3(x^2-3x+3)$ is not zero in $(1,0)$. Let $f=f(q)$ be this smooth solution with $f(0)=1$, $F(q,f(q))=0$.

We can not apply (IFT) to the function $F=F(w,x)$, but Kopal (1959) claims that $F$ admits an implicit function $g$ as a solution for $F(w,g(w))=0$, so that $g$ "factorizes" through the composition with $f$, explicitly $g(w)=f(q(w))$. Moreover, $g$ should have the described Taylor polynomial expansion around $0$ modulo $O(w^4)$.

---

It is then *enough to verify* this published solution. I will use CAS support, here  [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), to investigate the situation. We will find all five solutions of the given problem in the power series ring of power series in $w$ (modulo some rather small power of $w$) over the field $F=\Bbb Q(u)$, $u$ being a primitive root of third order.

---

So let us consider $S$, the power series ring  $\Bbb Q[[\; w\;]]$, and search for solutions $g=g(w)\in S$ for $F(w, g(w))=0$.

Because $F(0,x)=0$ has the roots (with multiplicities) $1,1,1,u,u^2$, we have five potential solutions $g$ starting respectively with these constant coefficients. We will search for (one, later three) solutions of the shape $g(w)=1+aw+O(w^2)$, and (later also) $u+aw+O(w^2)$, and $u^2+aw+O(w^2)$. Here, $a$ is an unknown.

We compute using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) in a power series ring, where we have also arranged for the existence of a "parameter" $a$, in the following setting

```
F.<u> = CyclotomicField(3)
S.<a> = PolynomialRing(F)
R.<w> = PowerSeriesRing(S, default_prec=20)

def F(q, x):
    return (1+q)*x^5   - (2+3*q)*x^4   + (1+3*q)*x^3   - x^2 + 2*x - 1

q = 3*w^3 / (1 - 3*w^3)
```

(with objects that should be mathematically clear)
the following expansion of $F(w,\ 1+aw)$, taken modulo $O(w^5)$:

```
sage: F(q, 1 + a*w) + O(w^5)
(3*a^3 + 3)*w^3 + (3*a^4 + 6*a)*w^4 + O(w^5)
```

In case of a zero result in $R$, we have to arrange that the coefficient in $w^3$ vanishes, i.e. $a^3=-1$. There are three solutions, $-1,-u,-u^2$. And we will follow soon only the main path $a=-1$ (relevant for the OP) first. The choice of $a$ determines three brances 
$$
\begin{aligned}
g_1(w) &= 1-w+O(w^2)\ ,\\
g_2(w) &= 1-uw+O(w^2)\ ,\\
g_3(w) &= 1-u^2w+O(w^2)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
For $g_1$ we search then the next approximation of the shape $1-w+aw^2*O(w^3)$. The code

```
sage: F(q, 1 - w + a*w^2) + O(w^6)
(9*a - 3)*w^4 + (-9*a^2 - 6*a + 2)*w^5 + O(w^6)
```

leads to $(9a-3)=0$, so $a=1/3$, so
$$
g_1(w) = 1-w+\frac 13w^2+O(w^3)\ .
$$
The next coefficient is extracted from

```
sage: F(q, 1 - w + 1/3*w^2 + a*w^3) + O(w^7)
(9*a - 1)*w^5 + (-12*a + 70/9)*w^6 + O(w^7)
```

so we get $a=1/9$ and the better approximation:
$$
g_1(w) = 1-w+\frac 13w^2+\frac 19w^3+O(w^4)\ .
$$
We can go on in this manner:

```
sage: F(q, 1 - w + 1/3*w^2 + 1/9*w^3 + a*w^4) + O(w^8)
(9*a + 58/9)*w^6 + (-12*a - 9)*w^7 + O(w^8)

sage: F(q, 1 - w + 1/3*w^2 + 1/9*w^3 - 58/81*w^4 + a*w^5) + O(w^9)
(9*a - 11/27)*w^7 + (-12*a - 280/81)*w^8 + O(w^9)

sage: F(q, 1 - w + 1/3*w^2 + 1/9*w^3 - 58/81*w^4 + 11/243*w^5 + a*w^6) + O(w^10)
(9*a - 4)*w^8 + (-12*a + 8867/729)*w^9 + O(w^10)

sage: F(q, 1 - w + 1/3*w^2 + 1/9*w^3 - 58/81*w^4 + 11/243*w^5 + 4/9*w^6 + a*w^7) + O(w^11)
(9*a + 4979/729)*w^9 + (-12*a - 6523/2187)*w^10 + O(w^11)
```

Thus:
$$
g_1(w) = 
1-w+\frac 13w^2+\frac 19w^3
-\frac{58}{81}w^4
+\frac{11}{243}w^5
+\frac 4 9 w^6
-\frac{4979}{6561}w^7
+O(w^8)\ .
$$
Because $F=F(w,x)$ depends "only on $w^3$", (i.e. factorizes through $w\to w^3$,) it is clear that
$$
\begin{aligned}
g_2(w) &= g(uw)\ ,\\
g_3(w) &= g(u^2w)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
are also (exactly the other two) solutions in $1+O(w)$ (defined after passing to the cyclotomic field, or to $\Bbb C$).

---

Not needed indeed, but to have all solutions of the quintic in $x$, we search also for $g_4,g_5$.

```
sage: F(w, u + a*w) + O(w^2)
(-9*a - 4*u + 2)*w + O(w^2)

sage: F(w, u + (2-4*u)/9*w + a*w^2) + O(w^3)
(-9*a + 56/27*u - 98/27)*w^2 + O(w^3)

sage: F(w, u + (2-4*u)/9*w - (98-56*u)/27*w^2 + a*w^3) + O(w^4)
(-448/27*u + 784/27)*w^2 + (-9*a + 1316/81*u + 350/81)*w^3 + O(w^4)

sage: F(w, u + (2-4*u)/9*w - (98-56*u)/243*w^2 + a*w^3) + O(w^4)
(-9*a - 28/81*u + 1162/243)*w^3 + O(w^4)

sage: F(w, u + (2-4*u)/9*w - (98-56*u)/243*w^2 + (1162-84*u)/2187*w^3 + a*w^4) + O(w^5)
(-9*a - 7184/6561*u - 35482/6561)*w^4 + O(w^5)
```

From here we can extract $g_4(w)$, so that $g_4(w)=u+\frac{2-4u}9w+\dots$  , and for algebraic reasons, the Galois transformation $u\to u^2$ applied on $g_4$ delivers $g_5(w)=u^2+\dots$

---

A final remark. If we work algebraically as above, it is questionable if at each "step" we obtain a (linear) equation in $a$, that can be solved. (I.e. $a$ appears (linearly) with a non-zero coefficient.) This needs a more specialized study. But Kopal (1959) claims only a result modulo $O(w^4)$, not an analytic expansion (with controlled coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ localized in $3$).

---

---

**Later EDIT:** There are some questions in the comments, i am trying to comment on them. (Here, since my style is not fitting in the margin of the comment.) First of all, this is a wonderful question. Answering it in a target oriented manner does 
not give full explanation of the structure. So understanding the full setting has at least two points: (I) Which is the asymptotics of a solution $x=x(q)$ of the given quintic with $x(0)=1$? Is it a power series in $q$? (No.) A fractional power series maybe? (Yes. In $q^{1/3}$.) (II) Find it explicitly in terms of a given uniformizer. (In the OP it is $w$, a constant times $q^{1/3}+O(q^{2/3})$.) I did above only (II), checking the prescribed expansion in Kopal (1959). Some words on (I), and (II).

**(I)** Find a dependency $x=x(q)$ explicitly or at least say something about its "asymptotics". This is beautifully done in the answer of [Simply Beautiful Art](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/272831/simply-beautiful-art), please consider giving full cretit to his  answer, and he  explains exactly the first step(s) to be done. He is writing $x=1+y$, so $y$ is now around zero, and (equivalently written) gets the Taylor expansion of the function $f$ from the given equation $f(q,x)=0$, i.e. $f(q, 1+y)=0$ around $(q,y)=(0,0)$. Let us do it here also:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(q.1+y)
&=f(q,x)_{\text{in }x=1+y}
\\
&=\Big(\ (x-1)^3(x^2+x+1) +qx^2(x-1)^3 +qx^3\ \Big)_{\text{in }x=1+y}
\\
&\equiv y^3(1+1+1+2y+y+O(y^2))
\\
&\qquad+qy^3(1+2y+O(y^2))
\\
&\qquad\qquad+q(1+3y+O(y^2))
\\
&\equiv 3y^3+q+\dots\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last line we have omitted terms in "higher order", where the "order" is still open, we may want to give different weights to $q$ and $y$. At any rate, for any such degree "order", the first components are $3y^3$ and $q$. To solve for $y$ depending on (a fractional power series expansion in) $q$, we have to arrange for the asymptotic $q\sim 3y^3$, i.e. $y\sim (q/3)^{1/3}$. In such a situation i would substitute $q=3z^3$, but for some reason, Kopal (1959) considers rather $q=3w^3/(1-3w^3)$. At any rate, this amounts to the same final information on the asymptotic of the solution around $q=0$. To obtain explicitly the expansion in terms of $z$, we can do the same as in this answer...

```
F.<u> = CyclotomicField(3)
S.<a> = PolynomialRing(F)
R.<z> = PowerSeriesRing(S, default_prec=20)

def f(q, x):
    return (1+q)*x^5   - (2+3*q)*x^4   + (1+3*q)*x^3   - x^2 + 2*x - 1

q = 3*z^3
```

and then

```
sage: f(q, 1+a*z) + O(z^5)
(3*a^3 + 3)*z^3 + (3*a^4 + 6*a)*z^4 + O(z^5)

sage: # so a = -1 above to cancel the term in z^3

sage: f(q, 1 -z + a*z^2) + O(z^6)
(9*a - 3)*z^4 + (-9*a^2 - 6*a + 2)*z^5 + O(z^6)

sage: # so a = 1/3 above to cancel the term in z^4

sage: f(q, 1 -z + 1/3*z^2 + a*z^3) + O(z^7)
(9*a - 1)*z^5 + (-12*a - 11/9)*z^6 + O(z^7)

sage: # so a = 1/9 above to cancel the term in z^5

sage: f(q, 1 -z + 1/3*z^2 + 1/9*z^3 + a*z^4) + O(z^8)
(9*a - 23/9)*z^6 + (-12*a + 9)*z^7 + O(z^8)

sage: # so a = 23/81 above to cancel the term in z^6

sage: f(q, 1 -z + 1/3*z^2 + 1/9*z^3 + 23/81*z^4 + a*z^5) + O(z^9)
(9*a + 151/27)*z^7 + (-12*a - 685/81)*z^8 + O(z^9)

sage: # so a = -151/243 above to cancel the term in z^7, and so on
```

and we get in this manner the asymptotic solution
$$
1-z+\frac 13z^2+\frac 19z^3+\frac {23}{81}z^4-\frac{151}{243}z^5+\dots
$$
i.e. explicitly in terms of $q$
$$
1
-\frac 1{\sqrt [3]3}q^{1/3}
+\frac 1{3\sqrt [3]3}q^{2/3}
+\frac 1{27}q
+\frac {23}{243\sqrt [3]3}q^{4/3}
-\frac{151}{729\sqrt [3]9}q^{5/3}
+\dots\ .
$$
**(II)** But even if we have the information above, the expansion in terms of $q$, the question wants the expansion in terms of $w$, so we have to redo the computation, or substitute the rather unnatural relation between $q$ and $w$... Instead, i did it directly in my answer, translating $f(q,x)=0$ as an equation $F(w,x)=0$ for which we have the information from Kopal (1959) that a power series expansion can be found. I really wanted to get his coefficients (and some more, supposing that they have some inner rule, but there is no such rule).

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer. Given the function $q=q(w)$ (or $w=w(q)$ for that matter), I understand the procedure. However, how do you find the appropriate $q=q(w)$ for a given $f(q, x)$?

Comment: @Matthias a brief look at this answer and I fail to see such, though you can find an explanation on the choice of $q,w$ in my answer.

Comment: @Matthias you may find some information in dan_fulea's answer on the choice of $q(w)$ from the line beginning with "Because $F=F(w,x)$ depends "only on $w^3$", (i.e. factorizes through $w\mapsto w^3$,) it is clear that"

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt "Because $F = F(w, x)$ depends only on $w^3$" is not satisfactory for me, simply because we _defined_ $w$ such that only $w^3$ appears in $F$. My question is, how do you know _a priori_ what an appropriate form of $q=q(w)$ is. To be more specific: would $q = 3w^3$ or $q=w^2$ also allow solutions of this kind (i.e. $q=q(w)$ is arbitrary and we simply follow the choice of Kopal (1959) here, or (stated in an another way), what argument does one have choosing $q=3w^3/(1-3w^3)$?

Comment: @Matthias see dan_fulea's edit.

Comment: @dan_fulea I give a brief explanation for why one uses $w=w(q)$ with $1+q$ in the denominator in my answer. The essence of it is to send $q=-1$ to $w=\infty$ so that it does not affect the radius of convergence of $w$. $q=-1$ is problematic because there is a singularity at this point, which can be easily see by the fact that we lose a degree of the polynomial at $q=-1$.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. It is all clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=y+1$ to get

$$(1+q)y^5+(3+2q)y^4+(3+q)y^3+q(y+1)^2=0$$

Note then we are considering $y\to0$ as $q\to0$, where $(y+1)^2\to1$ and $y^5$ and $y^4$ tend to zero faster than $y^3$, with coefficient tending to $3$. Thus, the dominating term is given by

$$3y^3\sim-q\implies y^3\sim-\frac q3\implies y\sim-\sqrt[3]{\frac q3}$$

which agrees with the first term of your expansion. It is notable that the writing this in terms of $q/(1+q)$ is a conformal mapping likely used to increase the interval of $q$ for which the series converges, since as $q\to-1$ at least one root will grow unboundedly as we lose a degree of the polynomial.

From there it is simply a matter of letting $w^3$ be defined as it is, rewriting everything in terms of $w$ using $q=3w^3/(1-3w^3)$, and expanding $y$ as a series.